# How do I address "SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired" on syncronization with pacman?

Tags: arch-linux, manjaro, pacman

In my latest monthly update, I ran into the following error:

```
$ sudo pacman -Syu
:: Synchronizing package databases...
error: failed retrieving file 'core.db' from repo.ialab.dsu.edu : SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
 core is up to date
error: failed retrieving file 'extra.db' from repo.ialab.dsu.edu : SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
 extra is up to date
error: failed retrieving file 'community.db' from repo.ialab.dsu.edu : SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
 community is up to date
error: failed retrieving file 'multilib.db' from repo.ialab.dsu.edu : SSL certificate problem: certificate has expired
 multilib is up to date
```

What is the standard, and most reliable way to resolve such SSL Certificate expiration issues?

I am using Manjero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the most expedient solution in my case was to run

```
sudo pacman-mirrors --country Canada,United_States
```

(You should replace the list of countries with whatever countries you are in and near.) This will automatically update the mirrors in `/etc/pacman.d/mirrorlist`.

I subsequently found this article, which goes into more detail about `pacman-mirrors`: https://www.fosslinux.com/4252/how-to-find-mirror-list-and-set-fastest-download-server-on-manjaro.htm

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced this problem but I got the solution:
Open **Add or Remove Softwares** and got to **Preferences** and than change your **official repositories** to **Canada** than **Refresh mirror lists**

It may work now